# Is the dot product a symmetric or anti-symmetric operator?

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory

To me it is clearly symmetric but I'm finding "the dot product is an anti-symmetric operator" in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03780
I'm not sure I properly understand what the authors are trying to convey. Any idea?

Comment: Well, for vector spaces over $\mathbb R$, the standard dot product is certainly symmetric.  In other contexts, for general inner product spaces over $\mathbb C$, say, you would normally have $<\vec v, \vec w> = \overline {<\vec w,\vec v>}$ where the bar denotes complex conjugation. Not sure if this is what you had in mind or not.

Comment: The dot product defined in the paper is over the set of vectors of real numbers.

Comment: I have no idea what the authors could possibly mean by "the dot product is an anti-symmetric operator."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant excerpt (which you should have provided):

> Two words are predicted to be similar if the dot product  between 
>   their  vectors  is  high.    But  the dot product is an anti-symmetric
>   operator, which makes  it  more  natural  to  interpret  these 
>   vectors as representing whether features are true or false, whereas
>   the dichotomy known versus unknown is asymmetric.

Your question is reasonable. The dot product is indeed symmetric - its value is unchanged when you switch the arguments. I suspect from the context that the authors are writing about vectors of unit length and mean to call attention to the fact that $(-A) \cdot B = -(A \cdot B)$ . Whether that interpretation makes sense depends on understanding the context more than I care to take the time to try.

Comment: best answer so far